# Reply section for blog comments focused on scroll

Tags: bug, blog

In the comment section of any blog article, whenever scrolling through comments on a mobile phone, the reply section is constantly focused (keyboard opens and screen scrolls down a bit to fit the reply section).
It's because when scrolling, touch is applied to the reply footer under a particular comment and so it opens the section.

This should not happen. The reply section should only open when clicked/tapped on the *Reply* text, not the whole Reply *div*.
It's very annoying the section constantly opening keyboard when I just want to read the comments.
I hope for a fix.

Comment: It’s because the «reply» button responds to «mouse down», instead of «mouse up» (simply speaking)

Comment: The blog is not "part of SE network", is it? (I have no idea where to report this type of concerns - posting it here looks totally useless to me despite existence of the corresponding tag)

Comment: We take blog bugs here, as does Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Another good reason for not reading the blog (mobile or not).